Open page is told to be closed. How can I access it again?
In Playwright I want to check if a click triggers a popup.
I thought I could do it this way: Define a promise, click and wait for the promise in a try/catch. This works as expected. (In my example I removed the handling of the dialog and the error).
My problem is, that in case the promise is not met, my page seems to be closed (but it stays open in the browser). I get: 'Error: locator.innerText: Target page, context or browser has been closed.' for the second console.log (but not for waitForLoadState('networkidle')).
What can I do to access page again?
  import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
  test('click, catching a non existing popup', async({  page  }) => {
  await page.goto('/');
  await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');
  console.log('************ Original page ***************');
  console.log( await page.locator('#maintitle').innerText());
  const dlg2Promise = page.waitForEvent('popup');
  await page.getByRole('button',{name: 'Referenzen'}).click();
  try {
    dlg2 = await dlg2Promise;
  } catch (error) {
    // Ignore if dlg2 does not appear
  }
  await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');
  console.log('*********** Page already here? ****************');
  console.log( await page.locator('#maintitle').innerText());
});


Please share an example site under test.

Handle promise properly and add some conditions to check if page is accessible
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('click, catching a non-existing popup', async ({ browser, page }) => {
  await page.goto('/');
  await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');
  console.log('************ Original page ***************');
  console.log(await page.locator('#maintitle').innerText());

  const dlg2Promise = page.waitForEvent('popup');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Referenzen' }).click();

  let dlg2;
  try {
    dlg2 = await dlg2Promise;
  } catch (error) {
  }

  if (!page.isClosed()) {
    await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');
    console.log('*********** Page already here? ****************');
    console.log(await page.locator('#maintitle').innerText());
  } else {
    console.log('Page is considered closed by Playwright.');

    // Attempt to re-attach to the open page
    const pages = browser.contexts()[0].pages();
    for (const p of pages) {
      if (p.url() === '/') {
        page = p;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!page.isClosed()) {
      await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');
      console.log('*********** Re-attached Page ****************');
      console.log(await page.locator('#maintitle').innerText());
    } else {
      console.log('Failed to re-attach to the page.');
    }
  }
});


Thank you! My problem as I described it is: I know that 'Page is considered closed by Playwright.'. So, what would I do next in the ELSE tree? The browser is open and the page is shown. I want to access it, and I want playwright to find it.

@Pauli you can re-attach to the open page.

How? I could not find out.

@Pauli
A. Retrieve all open pages in the current browser context.
B. Identify the original page based on its URL or other unique identifiers.
C. Re-assign the page variable to the identified page.

Thank you for your hints. On trying to implement them I found that the browser really closed in case no popup  is shown, but I could find a fix for that, and now my test runs as I expected it to run.

This looks really convoluted. There should be a simpler way to do this, but without a page under test it's pretty hard to provide a clear-cut, proven working solution.

I changed my code to retrieve all open pages as @BugHunter suggested.
The number of found pages after the try/catch is zero, when no popup is shown (and correctly 1, when it is shown).
But I found a strange solution of my problem: I entered a promise which would never resolve into the catch... Now page is found in case the popup is shown, and in case it is not shown.
test('click triggering reload, catching a non existing popup', async({    browser  }) => {
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page1 = await context.newPage();
  await page1.goto('/');
  await page1.waitForLoadState('networkidle');
  const dlg2Promise = page1.waitForEvent('popup');
  await page1.getByRole('button', {
    name: 'Hyperwave Root Collection'
  }).click();
  try {
    dlg2 = await dlg2Promise;
  } catch (error) {
  await new Promise(() => {}); // Never resolves
  }
  const allPages = context.pages();
  console.log('Number of open pages: ' + allPages.length);
  for (const openpage of allPages) {
    console.log("************* Title: " + await openpage.title());
  }
  await page1.waitForLoadState('networkidle');
  console.log('*********** Page has been reloaded ****************');
  console.log(await page1.locator('#maintitle').innerText());
});

